# Jquery checkbox selection

Tags: jquery

I have checkbox with the same name ,I need to get the selected value of checkbox in a array.(It should exclude non selected value). I have following code.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".t").change(function() {
        var allVals = [];
        $("input[name='checkbox1']:checked").each(function() {
            // alert($(this).val());
            allVals.push($(this).val());
        });
        $('#click').click(function() {
            $.each(allVals, function() {
                alert(this); // It alerts old past value also
            });
        });
    });
});


<input name="checkbox1" class="t" type="checkbox" value="1"/>a <br/>
<input name="checkbox1" class="t" type="checkbox" value="2"/>b <br/>
<input name="checkbox1" class="t" type="checkbox" value="3"/>c <br/>
<input name="checkbox1" class="t" type="checkbox" value="4"/>d <br/>
<input id="click" id="button" type="button" value="click" />
```

Here is a JSFiddle with my code -> http://jsfiddle.net/manseuk/VHSrZ/

Can anyone suggest how to solve it ?

Comment: **What error value?** We can't all read minds, even if you can.

Comment: I should get value of checkbox current selection. In my case It get printed all previous non selection also

Answer (score 2):

You could do:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var allVals;
    $(".t").change(function() {
        allVals = [];
        $("input[name='checkbox1']:checked").each(
        function() {
            allVals.push($(this).val());
        });

    });
});
```

In this way allVals is an array that contains only checked values

Fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/K6dTF/  (use firebug to check the results)

Answer (score 1):

You are binding a new click function each time you click a checkbox. You need to put this out of this scope, or unbind the function and rebind.

Something like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var allVals = [];
    $(".t").change(function() {
        allVals = [];
        $("input[name='checkbox1']:checked").each(function() {
            // alert($(this).val());
            allVals.push($(this).val());
        });
    });
    $('#click').click(function() {
        $.each(allVals, function() {
            alert(this); // It alerts old past value also
        });
    });
});
```

See fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/VHSrZ/3/

Answer (score 1):

Change your JS to the following :

It will alert an array of selected values

```
$('#click').click(function() {
    var allVals = [];
    $("input[name='checkbox1']:checked").each(function() {
        // alert($(this).val());
        allVals.push($(this).val());
    });
    alert(allVals);
});
```

Working example : http://jsfiddle.net/manseuk/VHSrZ/2/